# SQL Server 2014 - Weird datatype in a table

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2014, type-conversion

One of my tables has the data type of `(date(datetime)` when I expand it in object explorer but when I script out the create statement it shows `date` data type.

[image]

When I run a select script, I find that the column stores `datetime` data

[image]

So now my question is why the `"CREATE TABLE"` script is showing a wrong data type?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using SQL Server 2014 as your database engine instead of just using SSMS 2014?. What's the result of `SELECT @@VERSION`?

Comment: @Lamak Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64) 
 Jun 17 2016 19:14:09 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Is this a legacy database? Is it possible that there was an alias type `date` based on `datetime`, created in a version earlier than 2008, and then it was upgraded? If you look in `sys.columns`, what is `system_type_id`/`user_type_id` for that column?

Comment: @AaronBertrand This is a legacy database but it was on SQL server 2008 R2.

Comment: Are you 100% positive it was initially created on 2008 R2 and not upgraded from a previous version? Anyway, sys.columns will have more answers than screen shots of Object Explorer.

Comment: @AaronBertrand quoting my client here "I found out the databases were on some previous version but we don't know which version" , I am sorry, I didn't had this info earlier

Comment: @AaronBertrand System_type_id = 61, User_type_id = 257

Comment: List of all system_type_id : http://avian.netne.net/blog/?p=277

I could not find anything for the user type id.. Can you help me please?

Comment: User type id > 255 means it's a user type that the user created, so it won't be in some generic blog post because your 257 will be different from my 257. `SELECT name FROM sys.types WHERE user_type_id = 257;`, I bet the answer is `date`. Which means the table has an alias type called `date`, representing `datetime` as opposed to the 2008+ built-in type. You can fix it by saying `ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename ALTER COLUMN [LAST_SCAN_DATE] datetime --NOT NULL;`

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Every bit of your comment above made perfect sense and thanks to you I have made my client smile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Aaron noted in the comments, it's because someone created a custom datatype called DATE that pointed to the DATETIME datatype.

You can fix it (test first in development) by saying:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename ALTER COLUMN [LAST_SCAN_DATE] datetime --NOT NULL;
```